# File Upload Error in Apache Tomcat 7.0.52

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

```
    String TMP_DIR_PATH = "c:\\tmp";
    File tmpDir = new File(TMP_DIR_PATH);
    String[] lines = null;
    int count = 0;
    String size = null;
    String key = null;
    String userid = null;
    String filename = null;
    String nameid="";
    String master="";
    String sec="";
        String pub="";
    try {
        DiskFileItemFactory fileItemFactory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        fileItemFactory.setSizeThreshold(1 * 1024 * 1024); //1 MB
        fileItemFactory.setRepository(tmpDir);
        ServletFileUpload uploadHandler = new ServletFileUpload(fileItemFactory);
        List items = uploadHandler.parseRequest(request);
        Iterator itr = items.iterator();
        int a1;
        int a2;

        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            FileItem item = (FileItem) itr.next();
            if (item.isFormField()) {
                //     if (item.getFieldName().equals("key_")) {
                //       key = item.getString();                                                               
                // }
            } else {
                String str = IOUtils.toString(item.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
                filename = item.getName();
                //item.getInputStream().
                lines = str.split("\r\n|\r|\n");
               nameid= (String)session.getAttribute("userid");
               sec=Utilities.stringtoByte(filename+filename.length());
               pub=Utilities.stringtoByte(nameid); 
               master=Utilities.stringtoByte(pub+sec);
              // a1=Utilities.stringtoByte(filename); 
              // a2=Utilities.stringtoByte(filename.length()+""); 
            //   master= Integer.toBinaryString((a1&a2)); 

               // size = lines.length + "";
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
```

I am getting an error in the line

```
List items=uploadHandler.parseRequest(request)
```

It says that `httpservletrequest cannot be converted to requestcontext`. I don't know how to resolve that error.

Comment: Can you replace List add these two lines? Part filePart = request.getPart("fileName"); /* Assuming fileName is fieldName in form */
InputStream filecontent = filePart.getInputStream